# nginx is not caching proxied responses on disk, even though I ask it to

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy

I'm using nginx as a load-balancing proxy, and I would also like it to cache its responses on disk so it doesn't have to hit the upstream servers as often.

I tried following the instructions at http://wiki.nginx.org/ReverseProxyCachingExample. I'm using nginx 1.7 as provided by Docker.

Here's my nginx.conf (which gets installed into `nginx/conf.d/`):

```
upstream balancer53 {
    server conceptnet-api-1:10053;
    server conceptnet-api-2:10053;
}

proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:1g max_size=1g;

server {
    listen 80;
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types application/json;
    charset utf-8;
    charset_types application/json;

    location /web {
        proxy_pass http://balancer53;
        proxy_set_header X-Remote-Addr $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control X-RateLimit-Limit X-RateLimit-Remaining X-RateLimit-Reset;
    }
    location /data/5.3 {
        proxy_pass http://balancer53;
        proxy_set_header X-Remote-Addr $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control X-RateLimit-Limit X-RateLimit-Remaining X-RateLimit-Reset;
    }

    location /data/5.2 {
        # serve the old version
        proxy_pass http://conceptnet52:10052/;
        proxy_set_header X-Remote-Addr $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control X-RateLimit-Limit X-RateLimit-Remaining X-RateLimit-Reset;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
        rewrite ^/static/(.*)$ /$1;
    }
}
```

Despite this configuration, nothing ever shows up in `/data/nginx/cache`.

Here's an example of the response headers from the upstream server:

```
$ curl -vs http://localhost:10053/data/5.3/assoc/c/en/test > /dev/null
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 10053 (#0)
> GET /data/5.3/assoc/c/en/test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:10053
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server gunicorn/19.1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: gunicorn/19.1.1
< Date: Thu, 06 Nov 2014 20:54:52 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 1329
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
< X-RateLimit-Reset: 1415307351
< 
{ [data not shown]
* Closing connection 0
```

Each upstream server is enforcing a rate limit, but I am okay with disregarding the rate limit on cached responses. I was unsure whether these headers were preventing caching, which is why I told nginx to ignore them.

What do I need to do to get nginx to start using the cache?

Comment: If you use Mac with VirtualBox for Docker, it's recommended to turn **sendfile off**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running nginx alone with that nginx.conf, and found that it complained about some of the options being invalid. I think I was never successfully building a new nginx container at all.

In particular, it turns out you don't just put any old headers in the `proxy_ignore_headers` option. It only takes particular headers as arguments, ones that the proxy system cares about.

Here is my revised nginx.conf, which worked:

```
upstream balancer53 {
    server conceptnet-api-1:10053;
    server conceptnet-api-2:10053;
}

proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:100m max_size=100m;

server {
    listen 80;
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types application/json;
    charset utf-8;
    charset_types application/json;

    location /web {
        proxy_pass http://balancer53;
        proxy_set_header X-Remote-Addr $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }
    location /data/5.3 {
        proxy_pass http://balancer53;
        proxy_set_header X-Remote-Addr $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
        rewrite ^/static/(.*)$ /$1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Official documentation tells *If the header includes the “Set-Cookie” field, such a response will not be cached.* Please check it out [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid).

To make cache working use hide and ignore technique:

```
location /web {
  ...
  proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
}
```

Comment: I included the complete upstream headers in my question. Set-Cookie isn't one of them. My application doesn't use cookies.

Comment: Check proxy cache key and files created on disk